# How to resolve the issue in running appium driver on Android

Tags: java, android, testing, selenium, appium

Trying to run a sample testing for Android using appium. Setup for appium is done with node.js backend.

I have searched in the Appium mailing lists for the following error. But still I am unable to resolve this with a clear answer. This should be a simple issue on setup method. Can anyone point out the issue here?

Here is the setup code:

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        File app = new File( "/home/karthi/android/codebase/Sample/bin/TestingActivity-debug.apk");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Browser");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.1.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName","Appium");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.1.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("autoLaunch", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
        capabilities.setCapability("device-orientation", "portrait"); 
        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("app-package", "com.hola.sampleapp");
        capabilities.setCapability("app-activity", ".activities.TestingActivity");
        driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }
```

I am getting the following error when trying to run this in Eclipse in Ubuntu 14.04

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:17:32'
System info: host: 'spark', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-24-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:589)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:81)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:43)
at com.hola.testingapp.TestActivity.setUp(TestOuffy.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at     java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.fallBackExecute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:322)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:301)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:568)
... 30 more

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.yml.ouffytest.TestOuffy.tearDown(TestOuffy.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible causes:

You are giving localhost as IP, ensure to match it with the IP on which appium started including port.

You are running test on an Emulator with android version lower than 4.2

Comment: Is it necessary at all to specify the host and post as far as they are both default?

Answer (score 1):

Provide IP address and port same as appium setup ip and port.

Change your version to latest or above 4.1.2 , and remove

```
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Browser");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a very old question. But [here](https://github.com/manupsunny/AndroidTest) is a sample working template for Android functional testing framework using Appium, which is in Java and starts Appium server from within the code.